# Voluntary Suggested Edit for users with Edit privileges

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, suggested-edits

I would like to be able to make a suggested edit, even though I have the privilege to make an edit without moderation. I don't care about the reputation bonus (you can make that go away for suggested edits of users with > 2k reputation). I just want a more experienced user to determine whether my post is appropriate. To be clear, I don't have a problem with a user with less than or equal to my reputation accepting my edit because they would have the choice of clicking "Not Sure" if they felt they were not experienced enough to accept the edit.

Some quick background to help illuminate my problem. I am fairly new to Stack Overflow (only have had an account for 10 days). I am very active and have gained enough reputation to get the edit privilege. I have learned a lot about the culture of what is versus what is not appropriate in many situations. However, I realize that I still have quite a lot to learn. I would like to be able to make edit suggestions which I think are appropriate but am not sure about and let someone else decide.

Comment: Damn... 2k in 10 days... looks like we have a new player here.

Comment: yeah, each day more than 200 rep.

Comment: I must admit, this site is very addictive, I'm not sure why.

Comment: As an alternative I suggest this: make use of your newly-earned privilege to simply edit the questions you feel are wrong. Then occasionally go back and see if someone re-edited it. If someone did, learn from it. If SO trusts you to edit, it's *usually* right ;-)

Comment: I was a bit slower (around 15 days), so this is a valid request. I only learn how to make good edits later one when I participate in Meta.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think this is a good idea. If you're not sure about what you want to edit, just don't edit. Simple as that. Developing such a complex thing is not worth the minor gain. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd No need to develop a complex thing, just link the edit privilege with `Strunk & White badge` instead of 2K rep.

Comment: @Aziz how will this help? The developers will have to add another field in database, add code, add user interface etc.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Edit reviews do help in making good edits, new users learn from it. I agree that developers may have to add code but surely it is not a complex thing because privilege checks are already in place, they may have to add an `AND condition` to check if the person has 2K rep and Strunk & White badge.

Comment: This is not a complex feature. The functionality for putting an edit into the peer review queue is already there; just some piece of code tests your reputation, compares it to some configured value, and skips the peer review queue. Just some form checkbox is needed which will skip that test and go to the queue.

Comment: In science, we do not suddenly absolve researchers from having their work peer reviewed because they have a high reputation, or have put in 15 years of work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though rather inconvenient, you could simply make edits through an alternate account or as an anonymous user while logged out.

You wouldn't get any points (which you've said you don't mind).  You wouldn't make any progress towards editing related badges, which you might mind.  It might look funny if you were editing questions with one account while also answering with your main account, but as long as you don't engage in any voting shenanigans (and maybe put an explanation in the alt account's description) it shouldn't raise too many eyebrows.

So, if your goal is just altruistic improvement of the site, there are means at your disposal that don't require any new features.  (Though it's not a bad idea.)

Comment: Just to clarify my "answered" flag. I would still appreciate this feature, but this is a workable solution for now.