# Can I voluntarily cast a single close vote despite having a gold badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, vote-to-close, dupehammer

Voting to close as duplicate can be done by gold-badge owners without requiring votes from other people ("dupehammer"). This is often sensible and useful. However, is it possible to situationally cast only a regular/weak close vote, waiving gold-badge privileges?

Occasionally, maybe in a tenth of cases, I would prefer others to confirm my vote. The alternative is to just post a link to a potential dupe into a comment instead of casting an actual vote. But that feels like losing access to a tool (i.e. weak close vote) due to a badge-privilege.

Comment: @bobble No, but [How Do I Opt Out of Privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231507/168610) sort of does.

Comment: Well, from a technical point of view with respect to how the system works, you should be able to: 1) edit the tag(s) for which you have a gold badge out of the question, 2) cast your close-vote, and then 3) edit the tag(s) back into the question (which should be consolidated back into your original edit, creating a null-edit). I'm not saying that's a good idea as something that people should do, just that it should allow you to cast the non-hammer close-vote you're wanting to cast.

Comment: @Makyen Interesting hack, but I wouldn't put it past the stack engine to retroactively promote the close vote back to hammer-level.

Comment: @bitmask That's, of course, possible, but I doubt it would happen, as the check on the special capabilities of an individual close-vote would normally be done when the vote is cast. IIRC, I believe I've seen Meta posts indicating that close-votes from users who recently gained their gold badge (and recently promoted moderators) are not promoted, even when another vote is cast by a different user.

Comment: The only circumstances I'm aware of where something similar does change with respect to current user status is for moderator delete-votes on currently deleted posts. In that case, the check on the delete-votes being from a moderator is performed when an undelete-vote is attempted to be cast on the post, so it's the current moderator status of the delete-voters which matters (i.e., delete-votes from an ex-moderator no longer prevent undeletion).

Comment: Yeah, if I'm not sure I just don't put in that dupehammer vote. I keep an eye on the question to see where it's going. Sometimes I'll just add a comment, "See [potential dupe link]" & see if others pick up on it. *'With great power comes great responsibility'*

Answer (score 8):

You can't. [Same problem that mods have really](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41062/add-a-way-for-moderators-to-cast-a-normal-non-binding-close-open-vote).

I tend to just wait for 3-4 votes and do the final one if I'm not sure